How to change monoid for option of endofunctor?
I want to combine two endofunctors in the context of Option. The combining I want is by composing two endofunctors into one via Category.compose. I found that MonoidK[Endo].algebra[*] instance for Semigroup[Endo[*]] satisfies my requirements. I am using Semigroup[Endo[*]] to make Option be monoidal over Endo.
Here is my attempt of implementing it, but it combines two endofunctions not with the Semigroup[Endo[*]] I want to provide, but rather via some cats.kernel semigroup instance for A => B.
import cats.*
import cats.syntax.all.*
import cats.implicits.*

val f: Endo[Int] = _ + 1
val g: Endo[Int] = _ + 2

val of = f.pure[Option]
val og = g.pure[Option]

given Semigroup[Endo[Int]] = MonoidK[Endo].algebra[Int]
val oh = Monoid[Option[Endo[Int]]].combine(of, og)

val res1 = // Some(9)
  oh.mapApply(3)

val res2 = // Some(6)
  Semigroup[Endo[Int]].combine(f, g).apply(3).pure[Option]

res2 is my desired result here. How can I fix it?

Let's add some debugging utilities:
// subtype of Endo[Int] which would print debug info in evaluation
case class EndoImpl(name: String, added: Int) extends (Int => Int) {

  def apply(a: Int): Int = {
    println(s"$name($a)==$a+$added")
    a + added
  }

  override def compose[A](g: A => Int): A => Int = g.andThen(this)

  override def andThen[A](g: Int => A): Int => A = (this, g) match {
    case (f1: EndoImpl, g1: EndoImpl) =>
      EndoImpl(s"(${f1.name} andThen ${g1.name})", f1.added + g1.added)
        .asInstanceOf[Int => A]
    case _ => super.andThen(g)
  }
}

Then let's modify the example a bit
val f: Endo[Int] = EndoImpl("f", 1)

val g: Endo[Int] = EndoImpl("g", 2)

val of = f.pure[Option]
val og = g.pure[Option]

given Semigroup[Endo[Int]] = MonoidK[Endo].algebra[Int]
val oh: Option[Endo[Int]] = Monoid[Option[Endo[Int]]].combine(of, og)

println("oh.mapApply(3)")
println(
  oh.mapApply(3)
)
println()

println("Semigroup[Endo[Int]].combine(f, g).apply(3).pure[Option]")
println(
  Semigroup[Endo[Int]].combine(f, g).apply(3).pure[Option]
)

It prints:
oh.mapApply(3)
f(3)==3+1
g(3)==3+2
Some(9)

Semigroup[Endo[Int]].combine(f, g).apply(3).pure[Option]
(g andThen f)(3)==3+3
Some(6)

Interesting:

the first implementation does NOT uses our andThen nor combine, so it is NOT a monoid combining Endo values using any of them
meanwhile the second implementation does combine functions and then apply the value

Let's try to dig a big more. Both IntelliJ and VC Code+metals have utilities for previewing implicits passed arguments or used for conversions.
They let us see that the second (expected) implementation is roughly equal to:
val om: Option[Endo[Int]] = cats.kernel.instances.option.catsKernelStdMonoidForOption[Endo[Int]](
  summon[Semigroup[Endo[Int]]]
).combine(of, og)

which works as expected:

we combine functions within Some: (_ + 1) combine (_ + 2)
then we call the final function if it's not None

meanwhile the unexpected implementation is:
catsKernelStdCommutativeMonoidForOption[Endo[Int]](
  catsKernelCommutativeGroupForFunction1[Int, Int]
).combine(of, og).mapApply(3)

which is:

calling each function individually : (_ + 1)(3), (_ + 2)(3)
then combining results of each call with Semigroup[Int]: 4 + 5

It's a matter of implicit priorities and I would resolve it by manually constructing the expected instance and exposing it as given without priorities doing the guess work.
For debugging such issues I recommend getting familiar with related features in IDEs. I'd start with opening action/command palette and typing show implicit and looking what pops out there.
